# Error: P1001: Can't reach database server

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, nestjs, prisma

It seems to me that I have already tried all possible solutions to this error, but nothing helps. What am I doing wrong to connect the database? I tested the connection via vs code extensions and everything works great.

**Connection url for Prisma**

```
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://postgres:8aK3e3L6EfbA@postgres:5432/habits_tracker?schema=public&connect_timeout=300&connection_limit=5
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
services:
  frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    build: ./habits-tracker-frontend
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
  backend:
    container_name: backend
    build: ./habits-tracker-backend
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '3001:3001'
    depends_on:
      postgres:
        condition: service_healthy
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 8aK3e3L6EfbA
      POSTGRES_DB: habits_tracker
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    healthcheck:
      test: ['CMD', 'pg_isready', '-U', 'postgres', '-d', 'habits_tracker']
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
  adminer:
    container_name: adminer
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
```

**Docerfile for backend**

```
FROM alpine

FROM node

WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 3001

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . ./

RUN npx dotenv -e .env.local -- prisma generate

RUN npx dotenv -e .env.local -- prisma migrate dev --name init

RUN npx dotenv -e .env.local -- prisma db seed

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

Comment: Doest't look as a solve for your problem, but it's also mistake: you have one password in docker-compose file at POSTGRES_PASSWORD env variable, and another one in connection URL.

Comment: Thx, but of course it doesn't work

Comment: You can't `RUN prisma migrate` or otherwise connect to a database from inside a Dockerfile.  [docker-compose "depends_on" doesn't work, dependency service is never built](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75305557/docker-compose-depends-on-doesnt-work-dependency-service-is-never-built) describes this case, for example.